# Can one update entities in a custom EntityStore?

Tags: entity

As far as I can see from the documentation there is no upsert (update-insert) if you have created/registered a custom store. The only way seems to re-register the whole store if you wish to upsert entities. I know you can hook up relational data (the docs give a SQLite example) but my question refers to a plain, one-by-one incremental approach.

Comment: I’ve done it before, but I remember it being really Jacky